# How to find datakey value of gridview on selected index changed property?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My gridview is like this but I am getting error when I select view button to find primary key value column on selected index changed. Please help me to solve the issue.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <Columns >
                <asp:TemplateField >
                    <ItemTemplate >
                        <asp:Button ID="btnViewComments" Text ="View Comments" runat ="server" CommandName ="select" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField ="forumId" Visible ="false" />
                <%--<asp:CommandField ButtonType ="Button" ShowSelectButton ="true" SelectText ="View Comments"/>--%>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Question">
                    <ItemTemplate >
                        <asp:TextBox ID ="txtQuestion" Text ='<%#Eval("question")%>' runat ="server" TextMode ="MultiLine" Height="100" Width ="350"></asp:TextBox>
                       <%-- <%#Eval("question")%>--%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <%--<EditItemTemplate >
                        <asp:TextBox ID ="txtQuestion" Text ='<%#Eval("question")%>' runat ="server" TextMode ="MultiLine" ></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>--%>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Poster Name">
                    <ItemTemplate >
                        <%#Eval("posterName") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate >
                        <asp:Label ID ="lblPosterName" Text ='<%#Eval("posterName") %>' runat ="server" ></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
                    <ItemTemplate >
                        <%#Eval("dateTim") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate >
                        <asp:Label ID ="lblDateTime" Text ='<%#Eval("dateTim") %>' runat ="server" ></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

my code is.....

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Int64 forumId = (Int64)GridView1.SelectedValue;
            Session["forumId"] = forumId;
            Response.Redirect("Thread.aspx");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: the following error has occured..................................Data keys must be specified on GridView 'GridView1' before the selected data keys can be retrieved.  Use the DataKeyNames property to specify data keys.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First you have to define field name in grid view declaration that which field you want to make datakey. for example if you want "forumId" datakey.than

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"
DataKeyNames="forumId">
```

and than you can access in this way

```
int intforumid = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Int64 forumId = Convert.ToInt64(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text);
        Session["forumId"] = forumId;
        Response.Redirect("Thread.aspx");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set [**`DataKeyNames`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx) as `forumId` like below

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames = "forumId" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

Since you haven't give any data key names in current solution `GridView1.SelectedValue` will not contain the value you expected

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to set [`DataKeyNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx) property to `forumId` like;

```
<asp:GridView DataKeyNames = "forumId" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to specify the unique column name in the gridview to be set under the Datakey tab.

From there, you would need to invoke the _selectedIndexChanged method on the behind page code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using gridview select event in your page.cs code then you just remove OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" from the aspx code of page of gridview.