# How to find the index of selected row by checkbox in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview with 2 column then `cell[0]` has checkbox and `cell[1]` has data
I want if checkbox checked and click button delete, find which the checkbox is checked and delete the the row.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White"
         BorderColor="Blue" BorderStyle="Solid" CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
         ForeColor="Black"  GridLines="Vertical" Width="656px" >
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
        <Columns>
             <asp:TemplateField>

                 <ItemTemplate>

                     <asp:CheckBox  runat="server" />
                 </ItemTemplate>``
             </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="picname" HeaderText="picname" SortExpression="picname" />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#99FF66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" BorderColor="#006600" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#33CC33" ForeColor="#0066FF" HorizontalAlign="Center" BorderStyle="Dashed" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="Lime" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#0066CC" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540461/how-to-find-datakey-value-of-gridview-on-selected-index-changed-property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out the following article:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prathore/gridview-delete-multiple-records-using-checkbox-in-Asp-Net-3-5/

Hope this helps...

Comment: it's beter answer in world, tankyou verymuch