# c# - System.notSupportedException 'Callbacks are not supported on TemplateField'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to fix my code as there are errors, 'Callbacks are not supported'

> System.NotSupportedException occurred   Message=Callbacks are not
>   supported on TemplateField because some controls cannot update
>   properly in a callback.  Turn callbacks off on 'gvShoppingCart'.

This is my coding for design source, ShoppingCart.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvShoppingCart" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnablePersistedSelection="True" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="True" Height="178px" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvShoppingCart_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDeleting="gvShoppingCart_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="gvShoppingCart_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="gvShoppingCart_RowUpdating" Width="614px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Product Name" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Image" DataImageUrlFormatString="~\Images\{0}" HeaderText="Image" ReadOnly="True">
        </asp:ImageField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Brand" HeaderText="Brand" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Double.Parse(Eval("Price").ToString())*Int32.Parse(Eval("Quantity").ToString()) %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This is for the ShoppingCart.aspx.cs file where the error happened.

```
Cart myCart;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["myCart"] == null)
            {
                Session["myCart"] = new Cart();
            }
            myCart =(Cart)Session["myCart"];
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                FillData();
            }
        }

        private void FillData()
        {
            gvShoppingCart.DataSource = myCart.Items;
            gvShoppingCart.DataBind(); //error comes up here
            if (myCart.Items.Count ==0)
            {
                lblGrandTotal.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                lblGrandTotal.Text = string.Format("Grand Total = {0,19:C}", myCart.GrandTotal);
                lblGrandTotal.Visible = true;
            }
        }
```

After I changed EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks from 'True' to 'False' a new error came out

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'DataKeyNames must be specified for
>   persisted selection to work.'

The error happened at the same code as the previous error. Which is,

```
private void FillData()
        {
            gvShoppingCart.DataSource = myCart.Items;
            gvShoppingCart.DataBind();
            if (myCart.Items.Count ==0)
```

This is my CartItem.cs, class file.
    public class CartItem
    {
        private int v1;
        private string v2;
        private string v3;
        private double v4;
        private string v5;
        private string v;

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set;}
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public CartItem()
    {

    }

    public CartItem(int Id, string ProductName, string Image, double Price, string Brand, int Quantity)
    {
        this.Id = Id;
        this.ProductName = ProductName;
        this.Image = Image;
        this.Price = Price;
        this.Brand = Brand;
        this.Quantity = Quantity;
    }

    public CartItem(int v1, string v2, string v3, double v4, string v5)
    {
        this.v1 = v1;
        this.v2 = v2;
        this.v3 = v3;
        this.v4 = v4;
        this.v5 = v5;
    }

    public CartItem(int v1, string v2, string v3, string v)
    {
        this.v1 = v1;
        this.v2 = v2;
        this.v3 = v3;
        this.v = v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post part or all the code of the data type of `myCart.Items`? E.g. is it `Item`, and if so, could we see the class?

Comment: Actually based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17540564/6741868), and [the MSDN for DataKeyNames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames(v=vs.110).aspx), you could add `DataKeyNames="ProductID"` or whichever is your unique identifier for Products.

Comment: @haruna When you turn `EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks =false`, what happens if you turn `EnablePersistedSelection=false` as well?